# Creating a Pyspark session takes approximately 25 seconds

Tags: apache-spark, session, pyspark

I am trying to work with PySpark using the MongoDB connector. But creating the PySpark session alone is taking almost 20 to 25 seconds which is hampering the performance of the service. I've also given the code snippet that I'm using to create a spark session. Can anyone please suggest me how to make it faster?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
my_spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("myApp") \
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/test/collection1" \
        .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/test/collection1" \
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.partitioner", "MongoPaginateBySizePartitioner") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: How often do you create a new SparkSession? If more than once, could you just reuse it instead?

Comment: @alxrcs I've the small python scripts which will be running from the nodejs service whenever required using the spawn method. So when the script is completed, the spark session gets destroyed automatically if I'm not wrong. Can you please suggest me if there is a way to reuse the spark session in this case too.

Comment: I think keeping the session active somehow would definitely help your performance, but I'm not really sure how to easily accomplish now that from nodejs atm, sorry. 

You could try taking a look at [Apache Livy](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/) and see if that helps, though.

Comment: Maybe instead of ephemeral Python scripts, you try having a long running script Python script listening to data sent to it? You can either use a socket, for example, or even another full blown REST service with Flask (or similar) in order to reuse the same session.

Comment: Were you able to make any progress on this?

Comment: @alxrcs Thanks for the suggestion. I created a separate python  rest api  for the service, which enabled me to create a global pyspark session object, which boosted the performance by skipping the creation of session object at every service call.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear it worked out. I'll post it as an answer then so the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of performance, it might be a good idea to reuse the same SparkSession as much as possible.

There are several options here: if your service is not in Python itself, you could create a second REST Python service that keeps the session up.

This should be simple enough with frameworks like Flask, FastAPI, Bottle, Falcon or similar.